# Assign sql value to a temp value

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to assign the value `SUM(Price)` into a variable using SQL so that in my follow up select I can use `SUM(Price)` and multiply it.

```
SELECT "Total", SUM(PRICE), "pricing" =0 , "Trend" =0 
  FROM Products
UNION ALL
SELECT "Forecast", SUM(ProductID) as test, "pricing" = SUM(PRICE) *2, "Trend" = 0 
  FROM Products
```

However, the output is giving me this. What am I doing wrong?

[image]

Comment: Please tag your question with the database you are really using.

Comment: It is not clear what you are trying to accomplish. What is your expected result?

Comment: Hihi I am using oracle apex. It's tied to an oracle database .

Comment: The forecast row pricing should be 2222.71*2 instead of 0.

Comment: Please read http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557 and the accepted answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you just want something like this:

```
select 'total', sum(Price), '0' as Pricing, '0' as Trend
from Products
union all
select 'forcast',sum(ProductID), sum(price)*2, '0' 
from Products
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT 'Total', SUM(PRICE), 'PRICING'=0, 'TREND'=0 FROM products
UNION ALL
SELECT 'FORECAST', SUM(ProductId), SUM(PRICE)*2, 0 as TREND FROM products
```